# how to return two custom uitableviewcells

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

Hi just trying to figure out how to load two different custom uitableviewcells into two different sections on my uitableview... Just not sure on how to proceed... here is the code I have currently

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Registration Button
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomRegCell";
    static NSString *CellNib = @"LogInCustomCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return cell;

}
```

/////// NEW ATTEMPT.... :( if you could call it that..

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.section == 0) 
    {
        //Registration Button
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomRegCell";
        static NSString *CellNib = @"LogInCustomCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        return cell;        

    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        //Registration Button
        static NSString *CellButtonIdentifier = @"CustomButtonCell";
        static NSString *CellButtonNib = @"LogInCustomCell";

        UITableViewCell *cellButton = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellButtonIdentifier];
        if (cellButton == nil) {
            NSArray *nibButton = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellButtonNib owner:self options:nil];
            cellButton = (UITableViewCell *)[nibButton objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        return cellButton;      

    }
    return nil;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `section` property of the `indexPath` variable:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) 
{
    // do this
}
else if (indexPath.section == 1)
{
    // do that
}
```

The section number is based on the order in which they appear. The first section you want to show in the tableView will be `0`, and so on.

Comment: right, Ill try else if.. but was doing if and It was crashing the screen when I tryed to load..

Comment: Then you probably had a 3rd section that you weren't expecting. I'm willing to bet you got an error saying something like that method can not return nil cell. Could you post the crash?

Comment: honestly I dont know how to write it so don't know the error.. I will update my code with what I have done.. its not giving me an error but its also not displaying the other custom uitableviewcell... I have been working on this for the whole day and I'm just brain dead atm.. like cant think straight at all... updating code now.

Comment: You need to learn how to debug (setting breakpoints, stepping, etc). You also seem to be hacking your way through this implementation (I answered another of your questions a few days ago) - I suggest you relax, have a beer and try a UITableViewController tutorial from scratch. You're trying to force yourself to learn at the same time as implementing an idea; you'll have an easier (and less stressful) time of it if you learn how UITableView works before trying to make something you want with it.

Comment: yea, I think your right. I know parts of this stuff but then sometimes the further I get into it feels like the less I know and then I get abit lost.. if that makes sense. I also find parts of objective C really illogical.. can get quite frustrating. anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: okay debugging has helped me figure out where I'm going wrong.. just gotta figure out how to fix, as soon as I return anything it jumps out of the method.